# Clarification on var and val in Scala

Tags: scala, immutability

I was expecting a compiler error with the following code:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val x = 10
    var y = x
    val z = y

    println("x: " + x)
    println("y: " + y)
    println("z: " + z)

    y = 100

    println("x: " + x)
    println("y: " + y)
    println("z: " + z)
  }
}
```

However, the code compiles and I get back the following output:

```
x: 10
y: 10
z: 10
x: 10
y: 100
z: 10
```

What's going on?

When you initialize a `val` to a mutable value (or vice-versa), does it immediately copy it? Does it do this for any class? Is it a deep copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example behaves the exact same way as C, java, python, or any other programming language.

I think you are really asking about the val/var immutable/mutable distinction.  Here's a clearer example:

```
class A(var s: String) {
  override def toString = s
}

val x = new A("first")    // a new A object [Object1] is allocated, x points to it
var y = x                 // y is pointed to x's referent, which is [Object1]
val z = y                 // z is pointed to y's referent, which is [Object1]

println(x)  // "first"
println(y)  // "first"
println(z)  // "first"

y = new A("second")       // a new A object [Object2] is allocated, y points to it

println(x)  // "first"    // note that x is still pointing to the same object [Object1]
println(y)  // "second"
println(z)  // "first"    // so is z

x.s = "third"             // the string *inside* [Object1] is changed

println(x)  // "third"    // x still points to [Object1], which now contains "third"
println(y)  // "second"   // y still points to [Object2]
println(z)  // "third"    // z still points to [Object1], which now contains "third"
```

Saying `y =` will always point `y` at a new object, not change the current object that `y` points to.  This means that saying `y =` can never change `x` or `z`.

If `A` were immutable (`class A(s: String)`), then the only difference is that the operation `x.s =` would be disallowed.  Everything above that would be exactly the same.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: See my updates.  I made a new example that actually shows the difference between val/var and immutable/mutable.

Comment: I would argue that it actually *shows the difference between val and var*: in case of val you would get a compile error if you try to use `x` in place of `y` in `y = new A("second")`, and it's unclear why you state that there is no difference in behaviour between value types and reference ones

Comment: @om, calling `y` a val vs. var has nothing to do with immutability.  The original example only has immutable objects.  Additionally, my example (aside from the last 4 lines) behaves identically to the original example, but it uses classes (A) instead of values (int).  Ergo, makes no difference: values and classes behave the same.

Comment: But the last four lines shows that in case of reference types, there is a single instance of [object1] which is shared between x and z, which **reference** [object1], it doesn't work like so in case of value types (think about another example -- the very same variable surpases function call as either argument or return value)

Comment: Okay, awesome. Thanks! Your example helped.

Answer (score 3):

val is immutable reference to the instance in case of reference class (including String) and immutable value (which is copied, not shared on assignment), in case of value types (Int, Char, Double, ...)

var is mutable reference and mutable value respectively

In fact Java and many other languages has the very same semantics

Comment: Ah! Makes sense. Thanks! (I'll select your answer when it lets me.)

Comment: I guess my confusion was that I was under the impression that Scala did not have value types. Everything was a class. I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: It has nothing to do with value types versus classes.  If you replaced ints with some class with mutable fields, it would behave the same.